# manipulate string date in Java

Tags: java

I have this method isFormatDateCorrect to return true, if this format(`NNNN@YYYY-MM-DD`) of date is correct, and this methods is corretcly.

```
public boolean isFormatDateCorrect(String date) {
   if (date == null || date.length() == 0) {
          return false;
     }                   //NNNN@YYYY-MM-DD
   return date.matches("([0-9]{4})@([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})");
}
```

and here I have the other methods of isValidDate, but I have error when I get the 
number of process, and year, month and day, I use date.substring(); but this methods return just false

```
public boolean isValidDate(String date) {

        int process_number, day, month, year, max_days = 0;

        if (date == null || date.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        //The correct format of date is NNNN@YYYY-MM-DD
        if (isFormatDateCorrect(date) != true) {
            return false;
        }
        //NNNN@YYYY-MM-DD(process_number@Year-month-day)
        process_number = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, date.indexOf("@")));//get process number
        year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(date.indexOf("@") + 1, date.indexOf("-")));// get year
        month = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(date.indexOf("-") + 1,  date.lastIndexOf("-")));// get month
        day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(date.lastIndexOf("-") + 1,  date.lenght()));//get day

        if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
            return false;
        } else {
            switch (month) {
                case 1:
                case 3:
                case 5:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 10:
                case 12:
                    max_days = 31;
                    break;

                case 4:
                case 6:
                case 9:
                case 11:
                    max_days = 30;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
                        max_days = 29;
                    } else {
                        max_days = 28;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            if (day < 1 || day > max_days) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

For exemple, in Main, when I test

```
String date = "1234@2014-12-25"
if(isValidDate(date) != true){
     System.out.println("This date is invalid");
}else{
System.out.println("This date is valid");
}
```

and the output is:

> System.out.println("This date is invalid");

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to check the validity of the date (after dropping the process number and the @).

Comment: This is the type of problem that can be easily solved by stepping through with a debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I ran your code and it prints "This date is valid" for me. Are you sure that you didn't miss any message on the screen? I copied your code and had to fix a spelling mistake "lenght" -> "length". Maybe your code wasn't recompiled successfully, and then you ran an old version.

However, in case you're not doing this stuff as a code kata, I suggest you use `java.util.Date`, or even better `java.util.Calendar`, or even better the new `java.time` package, instead of reinventing the wheel.

The Java API provides many methods for parsing and calculating dates and times. It supports locale, different calendars, time zones. And in case a meteor hits earth onto a slightly different orbit, changing something about the length of days or years or so (leap seconds, leap years and stuff), a Java update will fix your code - if you used the API. Or in case the atheists take over and change the year back to its original definition with 13 months instead of 12 (12 is just because of those egomaniac Roman emperors). I mean, nothing likely, but you never know, why duplicate the efforts by reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isValidDate(String inDate) {
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
try {

   dateFormat.parse(inDate.substring(0,( inDate.indexOf("@") - 1 ));
} catch (ParseException pe) {
  return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Use this simle trick.